# Accessing table TH element using WATIR

Tags: watir, firewatir, watir-webdriver

I need to check if a certain column is displayed in the table.
Each column has a TH header with an unique ID.
What would the best way to check for the existence on a TH element in a table?

Here is an example of the table code.

```
<table id="attr-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="attr-action-col"><input type="checkbox" value="" class="attr-action-box" id="attr-action-col_box"></th>
      <th id="attr-name-col">Name<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n"></span></th>
      <th id="attr-type-col"></th>
      <th id="attr-scope-col"></th>
      <th id="attr-value-col">English Value</th>
      <th id="attr-master-col">Master Value</th>
      <th id="attr-translation-col">T</th>
      <th id="attr-workflow-col">Status</th>
      <th id="attr-history-col">H</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
....
</tbody></table>
```

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `th`, it should work in watir-webdriver, if it does not work in other Watir gems:

```
browser.th(:id, 'attr-translation-col').exists?
```

Answer (score 1):

generally the .exists? method is your best bet to see if a given element exists.  it returns true or false..

browser.cell(:id, 'attr-translation-col').exists?

=-=-=-= Edit to reflect stuff learned via comments and some resulting investigation =-=-=-=

the .cell method is implemented very differently in Watir vs Watir-Webdriver.  This does not appear to be included in the doc about the differences between the two.

In Watir, the *.cell* method is defined in the *Watir::Container* module and returns a *tablecell* object. This makes the *.cell* method available nearly anywhere from anything that inherets from *Container* or includes it.  For example the *IE* object.  The *tablecell* object is inhereted from the *Element* class, and thus has access to most of the expected methods such as *.exists?*

In Watir-Webdriver, the *.cell* method is defined in *Watir::CellContainer*. That module is included in *Watir::TableRow*, which means that (presuming I am understanding this correctly) the *.cell* method is only available from within a TableRow object, or something that includes *TableRow* or inherits from it. For example if you review a Watir-Webdriver *Browser* object, you won't see the *.cell* method listed.  Like Watir, the *tablecell* object is inhereted from the *Element* class, and likewise should have access to the *.exists?* method.

In contrast to *.cell*, the Watir-Webdriver methods for *.tr, .td, .th* are all defined in *Watir::Container* (as opposed to CellContainer) and thus are highly available and will usually work.

So what this analysis of the Rdoc's for the two projects is telling me is that if you can actually get your hands on a tablecell object in Watir-webdriver, you should be able to call the .exists? method, however you might find the number of places you can use .cell to get a tablecell highly restricted since few objects support this method. If you are seeing an error about a method not existing, it may well be the .cell method, NOT the .exists? method (where Watir-Webdriver is concerned)

Comment: Will browser.cell pick up the header TH cells?

Comment: Just tried it in IRB seemed to return true even when it wasn't on the page unless I having a face palm moment.

Comment: as far as I know .cell  matches both TH and TD tags, so should work.   there's no way .exists? should be returning true if it can't find the element, if so we've got a nasty bug   The ID value you tried is unique on the page right?  and for the 'false' test you used an ID like "DavesNotHereMan" that doesn't exist anywhere on the page correct?

Comment: I'll have another check when I get back in the office on Monday and let you know.

Comment: Tried this in webdriver, $browser.cell(:id => removedCol).exists? and I am getting this error; NoMethodError: undefined method `cell' for #<Watir::Browser:0x1310a64>

Comment: I presume 'removedCol' is a variable with a string value in it with the ID of a column that's no longer present in the DOM?  The no method error could be two reasons for that, one would be if the browser object was no longer attached to an instance of a webbrowser.  The other would be if for some strange reason watir-webdriver didn't implement the .cell element, but that seems unlikely to me as I thought it was pretty good at sticking to the elements defined by watir

Comment: @Alastair: I think `cell` method does not exist in watir-webdriver, try `browser.td`

Comment: Thanks @Zeljko and @Chuck, I've changed my test to check with the browser.td and browser.th methods

Comment: @Chuck I tried browser.cell(:id, 'attr-transaction-col').exists? where <th> has an id = 'attr-transaction-col' and it returns a false, so I guess the cell method does not work on <th> tag

Comment: Chaitanya, is the object in question in a frame by any chance?   If not are you using plain Watir, or Watir-Webdriver?  and for whichever one, what version?